# How to bind play events to AJAX loaded videos without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, events, html5-video

I know how to do with click events that are supported in every element. So this way I can use it for content that gets loaded later with AJAX.

But it seems the `play` event is only for `video` and `audio` tags. So I can not listen to it on the body right? How can add play events to every video that gets loaded later with AJAX without jQuery?

jQuerys `on()` would be the way right? Is there a standalone port of jQuery `on()` function I could use as a module?

```
document.body.addEventListener( 'mouseover', iframeEvent, false );
document.body.addEventListener( 'touchend', iframeEvent, false );
document.body.addEventListener( 'touchmove', iframeEvent, false );

function iframeEvent( ev ) {

    if ( ! ev.target ) {
        return;
    }

    const ele = ev.target;

    if ( ele.matches( 'iframe' ) ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events on things like `<audio>` and `<video>` don't bubble to parent element that's why the usual delegation scheme

```
document.body.addEventListener( 'play', iframeEvent, false );
```

won't work. But you can use the "capture phase" of the event by passing the 3rd parameter to true

```
document.body.addEventListener( 'play', iframeEvent, true);
```

More here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html